# Is there a way to set priority for the if condition rather than the next lines of code?

Tags: angularjs, api, if-statement

I have a api data, fetching it and showing it in website using AngularJS. I am just trying to store the api data in local storage rather than fetching data from api everytime. So I coded like this:

```
       if($window.localStorage.cityApi){
            $scope.cities = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.cityApi);
        }
        AddCityService.init(function(city_response) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.cities = city_response.data;
            $scope.city = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getCity($stateParams._id)));
            $window.localStorage.cityApi = JSON.stringify($scope.cities);
        });
```

But the problem is, it is taking the data from api, not from the local storage. If I comment the code of getting response from api. it will fetch from the local storage. If I also mention api along with the local, it will take the data from the api. I've checked in chrome developer tools. I can't use else condition too for this.because i have the pages to add the city and show the added cities. if i add the city once, that will redirect to the page to show the added cities. So, now if i use else here, that will not move to else statement itself, Hence it will not show the added city. Can anyone tell me is there any way to do this.

Comment: Why can't you put `AddCityService.init` in `else` branch?

Comment: i have the pages to add the city and show the added cities. if i add the city once, that will redirect to the page to show the added cities. So, now if i use else here, that will not move to else statement itselft. 
i think you understand my point

Comment: No, actually. It seems that you designed the logic poorly. Hence now you are trying to integrate another weird solution.

Comment: Then what is the best way to do it?

Comment: cities data should handled in the same way independently how you got them (from the API or local storage). In your case e.g. `$scope.loading` is not reset if the cities data are got from the local storage

Answer (score 0):

How is it possible that you can't use an *else* statement here?

```
if($window.localStorage.cityApi){
    $scope.cities = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.cityApi);
}
else {
    AddCityService.init(function(city_response) {
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.cities = city_response.data;
        $scope.city = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getCity($stateParams._id)));
        $window.localStorage.cityApi = JSON.stringify($scope.cities);
});
```

Does this not work?

Comment: Hello, i know this. but i am saying , i can't use else here. because if i add the new city from the form, it will not show the added city

Comment: Then I guess when adding a new city in the form you should simply push it to `$scope.cities` and possibly save it in the localStorage at the same time. Without seeing how you add cities I can't tell you more.

Comment: if you can't tell more, no problem . but if i do like you told. it will not show the already added cities.